# Wordpress custom .css styling dissapeared after pressing Customize in the Admin panel

Tags: php, css, wordpress, styles, customization

I had a fully functioning custom theme built but then I made the mistake of pressing Appearance->Customize in the Admin panel.
Now all my styles regarding menus are back to default and there is no way to override them. All other styles are working, the custom theme style.css is being used, but all the menus have reverted back to the blue vertical links and no matter what I do in my .css file it does not affect them.

Any ideas?

Comment: Has the class name for the menu changed?

Comment: Alex, ty. Indeed, something is overriding the class name of the nav container, that I have specified in wp_nav_menu. I installed a polyglot module for multilanguage support recently but where do I look for the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Though my best guess it that the problem was caused by installing a new Plugin.
Previously I used :

```
  $args = array(
          'theme_location' => 'header-menu',
          'container' => 'nav',
          'container_class' => 'site-nav'
        );
        wp_nav_menu($args);
```

And it worked, but stopped working.
Then I changed the container_class to 'menu_class' like so:

```
  $args = array(
          'theme_location' => 'header-menu',
          'container' => 'nav',
          'menu_class' => 'site-nav'
        );
        wp_nav_menu($args);
```

And it is working. It is giving the menu_class to the container. I still have to test if this custom menu_class is compatible with the multilanguage module.